# Incomplete response received in python rest request

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, python-requests

I am calling a rest api (get) using python request , it returns a huge response mostly (~50 mb) JSON and can some time be more.
Now the problem is response received is incomplete always , its not complete response that is retrived.

```
print("Doing rest call")
with requests.get('XXX', stream=True) as r:
    print("Rest Call Completed")
    text_file = open("data.txt", "wb")
    print("Size for the same is : " + str(r.content.__sizeof__()))
    for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=1024):
        text_file.write(chunk)
    text_file.close()
```

Once i open the text file i can see that the JSON is incomplete something like below , as a result i am not to able to process the same.
Can some one please guide how to retrive the complete JSON.
Please note the API call is pretty basic and dont pass any authentication / headers etc.

Response :

```
"XXX", "source": "XXX", "timestamp": "2021-01-22T08:17:43.259210Z", "payload": {"reason": "Packed", "XXX": "ed9cb952-b561-4305-abd7-534aa6e6b014", "quantity": -2, "actualQuantity": 10}}, {"id": "37f61e32-1dd8-4982-afa1-74f75b9cc03b", "causationId": "a6596e77-276f-4430-8b99-bfed54152e42", "correlationId": "a6596e77-276f-4430-8b99-bfed54152e42", "name": "XXX", "source": "XXX", "timestamp": "2021-01-22T08:17:43.275313602Z", "payload": {"XXX": "0440acda-2fb0-4583-89b0-28b2fd6dda20", "XXX": "292dc08f-0177-1000-953d-a134671294dd", "location": "sort-t
```